# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe'

Tags: django-views, stripe-payments

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe' Even I Have import into my views.py  fle

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
import stripe

STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY1=settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
# Create your views here.

def testing(request):
    return render(request,"login.html",{'key':STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY1})

def charge(request): # new
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=500,
            currency='usd',
            description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken']
        )
        return render(request, 'success.html')
```

Always Showing Error 
NameError at /charge/
name 'stripe' is not defined

Comment: Have you installed the stripe-python library? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python#installation

Comment: Sir it is always Showing error   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/raj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stripe-2.27.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.  Sir please let me know if you know how to solve it .

Comment: as the error states it cannot install due to user permissions.  try doing it as sudo or setup a virtual environment where you have full permissions

Answer (score 0):

May be you haven't install it in your enviroment,Try to install it using
**pip install stripe**
for more details see documentations https://pypi.org/project/stripe/

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Stripe? if not, try:

```
pip install stripe
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another reason may be that you are using venv but that you installed the module for the wrong version of Python. For example, compare these:

```
# install to default Python version, which might be, say, 3.10
# ...and then you'll get module not found if you expected to install it to, say, 3.9.
pip install -r requirements.txt

# install the module for 3.9 explicitly
python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```